# Changing server IP breaks webserver

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I start with a new ubuntu instance, I install mysql and apapche or nginx. The server works, the security groups are fine. If I start and stop the server, the webserver still works.

If I give it an elastic IP the webserver stops working. If I create a new server with the image of that server, it doesn't work because it has a different IP, although I can always SSH in anytime. Its just when it changes IP from when I create and install the box, the webserver stops working. It has the same security group and the webserver is running

Comment: could you please Edit your question to provide additional details? Please tell us exactly what steps you are performing and what is the result / errors you are experiencing. For example, it is unclear what you are doing when  you say you "create a new instance or give it an elastic IP" -- is that on the old instance, or the new instance? If it is a new instance, how can it stop, given that it wasn't previously running? The better you can describe your situation, the better the chance of us helping you to find an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your question, it is not clear what steps you are following. I will try and outline them, and hope this helps and is on the mark.

1. Create an image of you current server.
   (The process of creation will bring down your server for a couple of minutes.)
2. Verify image creation - then create a new instance but chose the AMI you just created for the new instance.
3. Either make sure you assign a IP address (check the box) if you want a static IP, or leave it empty if  you will immediately assign an ElasticIP after setup to your new instance.
4. If you chose ElasticIP then if it is running on an old instance it will be removed from the old instance and placed on the new. If you use a new ElasticIP then of course, you create one and attach it.

5 Your new machine should be on either the static IP it was given, or the ElasticIP you attached to it.

[If this is not clear start with the docs posted here.](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/launch-instance-custom-ami/)

It could be I did not fully understand the problem in your case but these are the basic steps.

Comment: thanks. i follow those steps and the security group works, but the webserver isnt working. The webserver is running and the box is accesible via ssh but I cant connect via http to that new ip

Comment: @mconnors this may seem obvious, but are you sure you are using the ***new connect string*** with the ***new IP*** that AWS gives you in the connect box?

Comment: yeah definitely, I am connecting to the box with the new IP in SSH, its just not accessible by browser by the new ip and I can't ping the new IP

Comment: Also it keeps redirecting the ip back to the old one, I didn't enter that ip address in any config

Comment: UGH idiiot! My bad, the default site was pointed at a wordpress site and since all the configs are stored in the db is was redirecting to an old ip